# Tensorflow: MLP for regression showing same predicted value for the testset

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow

This is the first time I'm working with Tensorflow. This is the implementation of a basic MLP for regression. The code is modified from standard MNIST classifier:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

I have only changed the input, output, hyperparameters, cost function to

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
```

and added this after out_layer

```
out = tf.sigmoid(out_layer)
```

I'm training on 4440 input data with 5 features and testing on 2956 data. After 3rd epoch, all values are same for the training set. The problem is that for the test set, I'm getting the same predicted value.

```
Training started...

Epoch 1

Loss= 0.001181 , y_pred= 0.485037 , y_actual= 0.450664
Loss= 0.014749 , y_pred= 0.206193 , y_actual= 0.32764
Loss= 0.000000 , y_pred= 0.323003 , y_actual= 0.323016
Loss= 0.028031 , y_pred= 0.276502 , y_actual= 0.109078
Loss= 0.024109 , y_pred= 0.283097 , y_actual= 0.127827
Loss= 0.000688 , y_pred= 0.222412 , y_actual= 0.196174
Loss= 0.022695 , y_pred= 0.285257 , y_actual= 0.13461
Loss= 0.043803 , y_pred= 0.228042 , y_actual= 0.437334
Loss= 0.002999 , y_pred= 0.251055 , y_actual= 0.30582
Epoch 2

Loss= 0.041213 , y_pred= 0.247654 , y_actual= 0.450664
Loss= 0.005612 , y_pred= 0.252729 , y_actual= 0.32764
Loss= 0.001075 , y_pred= 0.29023 , y_actual= 0.323016
Loss= 0.018882 , y_pred= 0.246489 , y_actual= 0.109078
Loss= 0.018060 , y_pred= 0.262215 , y_actual= 0.127827
Loss= 0.001204 , y_pred= 0.23087 , y_actual= 0.196174
Loss= 0.018622 , y_pred= 0.271072 , y_actual= 0.13461
Loss= 0.038593 , y_pred= 0.240883 , y_actual= 0.437334
Loss= 0.002938 , y_pred= 0.251615 , y_actual= 0.30582
Epoch 3

Loss= 0.041822 , y_pred= 0.24616 , y_actual= 0.450664
Loss= 0.005700 , y_pred= 0.252141 , y_actual= 0.32764
Loss= 0.001073 , y_pred= 0.29026 , y_actual= 0.323016
Loss= 0.018882 , y_pred= 0.24649 , y_actual= 0.109078
Loss= 0.018059 , y_pred= 0.26221 , y_actual= 0.127827
Loss= 0.001203 , y_pred= 0.230861 , y_actual= 0.196174
Loss= 0.018622 , y_pred= 0.271074 , y_actual= 0.13461
Loss= 0.038595 , y_pred= 0.240879 , y_actual= 0.437334
Loss= 0.002938 , y_pred= 0.251613 , y_actual= 0.30582
Epoch 4

Loss= 0.041822 , y_pred= 0.24616 , y_actual= 0.450664
Loss= 0.005700 , y_pred= 0.252141 , y_actual= 0.32764
Loss= 0.001073 , y_pred= 0.29026 , y_actual= 0.323016
Loss= 0.018882 , y_pred= 0.24649 , y_actual= 0.109078
Loss= 0.018059 , y_pred= 0.26221 , y_actual= 0.127827
Loss= 0.001203 , y_pred= 0.23086 , y_actual= 0.196174
Loss= 0.018623 , y_pred= 0.271074 , y_actual= 0.13461
Loss= 0.038595 , y_pred= 0.240879 , y_actual= 0.437334
Loss= 0.002938 , y_pred= 0.251613 , y_actual= 0.30582

Training Finished!

Testing started...

Loss= 0.010336 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.348012
Loss= 0.123387 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.597613
Loss= 0.005033 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.175401
Loss= 0.022147 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.0975305
Loss= 0.004484 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.313307
Loss= 0.010506 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.348845
Loss= 0.000052 , y_pred= 0.246348 , y_actual= 0.239131
```

I have tried all the possible solutions provided by the various posts describing the same problem. Like the data is shuffled and normalized, dimension of y and pred are same.

1) [TensorFlow always converging to same output for all items after training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451874/tensorflow-always-converging-to-same-output-for-all-items-after-training)

2) [MLP in tensorflow for regression... not converging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898696/mlp-in-tensorflow-for-regression-not-converging)

3) [tensorflow deep neural network for regression always predict same results in one batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399609/tensorflow-deep-neural-network-for-regression-always-predict-same-results-in-one)

Here is the code. Thanks a lot.

```
# In[67]:

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# In[68]:

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
epoch = 1
dropout = 0.75
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 256 # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 256
n_hidden_4 = 256
n_input = 5
n_val = 1

train_set = 4440

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input], name = "x")
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_val], name = "y")
# keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)


# In[69]:

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    out = tf.sigmoid(out_layer)
    return out


# In[70]:

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32, name = "h1")),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32, name = "h2")),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "h3")),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "h4")),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_val], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "out"))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "b1")),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "b2")),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "b3")),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "b4")),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_val], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01 ,dtype=tf.float32,name = "out"))
}
# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
# pred = tf.transpose(pred)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[71]:

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training
    print "Training started...\n"

    for ep in range(1,epoch+1):

        print "Epoch",ep
        print
        num = 0
        with open('norm_rand_feature_y.csv') as f:

            for line in f:

                data = line.split(",")
                x_temp = data[0:5]
                y_temp = data[5]

                x_temp = np.asarray(x_temp)
                x_temp = x_temp.reshape(1,x_temp.shape[0])
                x_temp = x_temp.astype(np.float32)

                y_temp = np.asarray(y_temp)
                y_temp = y_temp.reshape(1,1)
                y_temp = y_temp.astype(np.float32)

                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: x_temp, y: y_temp})

                loss,y_pre = sess.run([cost,pred], feed_dict={x: x_temp,
                                                  y: y_temp})

#                 print tuple(pred.get_shape().as_list())
#                 print y.shape



                if num%500 == 0:
                    print "Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss),  ", y_pred=",y_pre[0][0],  ", y_actual=",y_temp[0][0]

                num = num+1
                if num == train_set:
                    break

#     variables_names =[v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
#     values = sess.run(variables_names)
#     for k,v in zip(variables_names, values):
#         print(k, v)

#     print sess.run("h1", feed_dict={x: x_temp,y: y_temp, keep_prob:1.0})
    print "Training Finished!\n"

    #Testing
    y_value = list()
    y_actual = list()
    error = 0
    num=0
    print "Testing started...\n"
    with open('norm_rand_feature_y.csv') as f:

            for j in range(train_set):
                f.next()

            for line in f:

                data = line.split(",")
                x_temp = data[0:5]
                y_temp = float(data[5])

                x_temp = np.asarray(x_temp)
                x_temp = x_temp.astype(np.float32)
                x_temp = x_temp.reshape(1,x_temp.shape[0])

                y_temp = np.asarray(y_temp)
                y_temp = y_temp.reshape(1,1)
                y_temp = y_temp.astype(np.float32)

                loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: x_temp, y:y_temp})


                y_pred = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: x_temp})

                print "Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss),  ", y_pred=",y_pre[0][0],  ", y_actual=",y_temp[0][0]

                y_value.append(y_pred[0][0])
                y_actual.append(y_temp)
                error = error + abs(y_pred[0][0] - y_temp)

#                 num = num+1
#                 if num == 100:
#                     break

    print
    print "Testing Finished!\n"
    error = error/(7396-train_set+1)
    print "Total error:",error[0][0]
    y_row = zip(y_value,y_actual)
    np.savetxt("test_y_mlp.csv", y_row, delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would try first :

- Try to play with the learning rate. Especially because you have a batch size of 1, it may be too high.
- Increase batch size (in your case feed your data by batch, start with batches of 16 maybe)
- An easy way to test if your implementation is correct is to try to overfit a very small amount of data. Take 10 sample and make 1000 iterations on these, you should be able to have a very low loss (1E-6 at least)

Comment: 1) I tried changing the learning rate from 0.1 to 1e-8. 2) formed a batch of batch size 16, 3) For learning rate 1e-2 to 1e-4, it gets a loss lesser than 1e-6 for 1000 iterations on 10 samples. Still the predicted value is same. Any other suggestions? Thanks.